# Redirect to https using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, certificate

I have a problem with .htaccess

I have a certificate in my server, and it's only for https://example.com (not https://www.example.com) Therefore, I'm trying to do a .htaccess redirect to the correct url.

My intention is this:

```
http://www.example.com --> https://example.com
http://example.com --> https://example.com
https://www.example.com --> https://example.com
```

I tried different combinations and nothing seems to work. At the moment I have this, but seems like is not working for

`http://www.example.com/subfolder`, I don't know what is failing...

```
RewriteEngine On

# Follow symbolic links.
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: What do you mean *"nothing seems to work"*? How does it not work? Does the browser complain about mixed content? See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I mean any of the different combinations I tried in .htaccess seemed to work... The result was not the expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your current code by this one

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "www" domain to https://example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect http to https (at this point, domain is without "www")
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

That code is not working for me, I found that, which works for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```