# Url is redirects to .shtml unknown link

Tags: .htaccess, http, url, https, http-status-code-401

I need to implement SSL redirection. The HTTP/https and non-www URLs should forcefully redirect to https://www URLs.

There exists browser authentication code in htaccess file and this is the reason behind which redirecting to https://exmpledomain/.shtml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to https using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191762/redirect-to-https-using-htaccess) - or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: If I remove browser authentication my redirection code is working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After the Authentication code please write this

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ ([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ ([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%2 [L,R=301]
```